# AdMob Ad Banner Showing on top of Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXDJN.png) to see what I'm talking about.

Some info: I made a game in Unreal Engine 4 and to make an app bundle for it I am using Android Studio.

For some reason the AD banner is showing on top of my Android A30 navigation bar... This issue hasn't been occurring ~2 months ago.

I am clueless on what to do, if somebody can help that would mean a lot thanks.

[Unreal Engine Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcBSK.png)

[Android Studio Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylvht.png)

Comment: Check the dimensions of both navigation bar and your Ad they might be colliding , and make sure to post snippet from your code also

Comment: Hey @HaseeBMir thanks for reaching out. I added some pictures to my question. Can you please tell me how can I change the location and the size of my banner in Android Studio? You can see that in Unreal I have no option to change the size or the location of the banner...

Comment: Can you post code snippet where you define dimensions ? I am sure its problem with dimensions or Auto Alignment